# Is it possible to access c drive (Windows installed) from kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, windows-10

When i boot onto kubuntu , sometimes i want to access files from (Windows drive) so then i end up rebooting again to Windows and moving files to another drive which is accessible from kubuntu. Is there any other way ,without crashing Windows files?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation look at the windows 8 / 10 section. After doing that, you can access the windows disk from the kubuntu file manager (it should be listed on the left).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer.

## Part #1

Although not recommended, you can directly get to files on your Windows C: drive by mounting that partition in Nautilus (by clicking on the disk icon in the Unity launcher). You need to properly prepare Windows for this to happen.

You'll need to do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows

## Part #2

A better way is to create a NTFS partition on your hard disk that can be shared in both Windows and Ubuntu. This NTFS partition can be auto-mounted in Ubuntu by editing `/etc/fstab` and adding lines similar to this:

```
# shared ntfs disk
UUID=0C0F93CE58153D42  /media/your_username/Shared_Data  ntfs-3g  defaults  0  0
```

changing the UUID to the correct value.

Comment: I would but my reputation is too low to upvote.

Comment: @freeezer98 you should be able to up **vote** by clicking on the grey up arrow just to the left of my answer, or **accept** by clicking on the grey checkmark just to the left of my answer.

Comment: Yeah but there is a pop-up showing me i can't upvote due to less than 15reputation.

Comment: @freeezer98 ah! and you're just short of that. Same thing for the accept checkmark?

Comment: About the ; type chkdsk /f c:

; It is showing me a output , cannot run due to other process, tried restarting but the same.

Comment: @freeezer98 after the chkdsk command, it'll say that, and ask for confirmation to run chkdsk at next reboot time. That's why I have the last two steps in Part #1.

Comment: @freeezer98 Accepting an answer doesn't depend on reputation. It's not the same as voting.